# The difference between class="with equal sign in front" and class:"with Colon"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby on rails,sorry if it's a dumb question.

Here i have an example of class=""

```
class="table table-striped"
```

and below an example of class: ""

```
class: "btn btn-primary btn btn-success"
```

Please explain to me what is the difference between them.
Thank you

Comment: Can you supply more of the code around where you are seeing this? Your first example looks like straight html.

Comment: My code is quite similar to the one i marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class="` is an HTML expression, while `class: "` is a Ruby expression.

You didn't give any context for where you are seeing these, so allow me to insert my own.

Say you have a view, `index.html.erb`, with the following markup:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <% @people.each do |person| %>
    <tr class="person">
      <td><%= person.first_name %></td>
      <td><%= person.last_name  %></td>
      <td><%= person.last_name  %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'View', person, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %></td>
    </tr>u
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Here, you can see that the `table` element has the classes `table table-striped`, and they are defined in the HTML using the first syntax.

On the other hand, the last `td` calls the `link_to` helper defined by Rails and passes the `class` argument in as a Ruby hash. The [documentation for `link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) shows that the method takes a hash named `html_options`, which is where the `class` argument ends up going.

Comment: Thanks a lot,you explained it in the best possible way.

Answer (score 1):

`class="table table-striped"` : This type of syntax shows up in HTML code. example: `<td class="right">Ticket Counts:</td>`

`class: "btn btn-primary btn btn-success"` : This type of syntax is used when it is ruby code. example: `<%= link_to 'Home', home_path, class: "home-link" %>`

This generates a `<a class="home-link" href="/" title="Home">Home</a>` html tag.

Answer (score 0):

The first one assigns the `String` literal `"table table-striped"` to a local variable named `class` (which is a bad idea, since `class` is a reserved word in Ruby, and you will have to jump through hoops to dereference that variable using the [`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) method).

The second is simply illegal syntax and will result in a `SyntaxError` exception being raised.

Syntax like this can only occur

- in a `Hash` literal:

  ```
  { class: "btn btn-primary btn btn-success" }
  ```

  where it will create a `Hash` with a `Symbol` key `:class` referencing a `String` value `"btn btn-primary btn btn-success"`
- in a parameter list:

  ```
  def foo(class: "btn btn-primary btn btn-success")
  ```

  which is an optional keyword parameter named `class` with a default argument `"btn btn-primary btn btn-success"` (which is again a bad idea, because `class` is a reserved word and you will have to use `Binding#local_variable_get` inside the method body to dereference it)
- in an argument list:

  ```
  foo(class: "btn btn-primary btn btn-success")
  ```

  here it is passing the `class` keyword argument with the `String` literal `"btn btn-primary btn btn-success"` as an argument to the message send `foo`

But it can never occur on its own like you showed it.

Comment: While this is true when you are working directly in Ruby, the question is referring to Ruby on Rails (see the tags), which implies that the `class="` that the OP is seeing comes from HTML, not Ruby.

Comment: @Jon: The question is specifically tagged with [tag:class], which refers to the programming concept of "class", not HTML. It is also tagged [tag:ruby], and there is absolutely no mention of [tag:html], [tag:haml], [tag:css] or anything like it either in the question or in the tags. In my experience, almost none of the questions tagged with [tag:ruby-on-rails], especially by beginners, are actually about Rails. (A couple of months ago someone was called out on this, and he said that his professor(!!!) told the students to tag every of their questions with RoR "so that more people see it".)

Comment: I've noticed that same trend. However, based on the context of the question (i.e. the class names `table table-striped`, and `btn btn-primary btn btn-success`) and some deductive reasoning based on common Rails practices, I feel that the implication I mentioned becomes rather obvious.